# Sub directory not getting copied to remote server using Rsync Linux

Tags: linux, incron

I tried with copying directory and files to remote Linux machine using rsync and incrontab.

It's working fine copying files to remote server.

**Incrontab**

```
/data/AMOS_SHARE/CHV_BE/ IN_MODIFY,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_MOVE /data/AMOS/jboss/chv_rsync.sh
```

**Rsync**

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod -R 775 /data/AMOS_SHARE/CHV_BE
rsync -avuzh  /data/AMOS_SHARE/CHV_BE/ jboss@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/AMOS_SHARE/CHV_BE/
```

I created some files in `/data/AMOS_SHARE/CHV_BE/` folder. It worked fine as well as I created folder in that, it is also working fine. But whenever I creat files in a sub folder, it's not working.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In incrond recursively monitoring is not implemented yet, so the events in sub-directories are not monitored. You can do it by adding a additional watchers to sub-dirs but I would recommended to use
another tool:

[Watcher](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2011-01/07-watcher_a_recursive_incron_alternative)

Also you can try ionotifywait tool (example)

```
inotifywait /tmp/test_dir -m -r
```

and parse the output of this command.